# Delete com sub-consulta IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

bom dia amigos !

Não estou conseguindo deletar com count SQL server alguem poderia dar um força?

Mensagem 116, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 32
Somente uma expressão pode ser especificada na lista de seleção quando a subconsulta não é introduzida com EXISTS.

```
DELETE FROM PROGRAMAS
    WHERE ID_GERAL IN
       (SELECT ID_GERAL, COUNT(ID_GERAL) AS TOTAL FROM PROGRAMAS
        WHERE   
        Programa LIKE '%BEM ESTAR%' AND 
        Programa NOT LIKE 'Bem Estar - Gilenya' AND 
        Programa NOT LIKE 'Bem Estar Melanoma' AND
        Programa NOT LIKE 'Bem Estar - ILARIS' 

        GROUP BY ID_GERAL
        HAVING COUNT(ID_GERAL) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu subselect, vc deve remover o TOTAL, a sua consulta deve ficar assim:

```
DELETE FROM PROGRAMAS
WHERE ID_GERAL IN
   (SELECT ID_GERAL FROM PROGRAMAS
    WHERE   
    Programa LIKE '%BEM ESTAR%' AND 
    Programa NOT LIKE 'Bem Estar - Gilenya' AND 
    Programa NOT LIKE 'Bem Estar Melanoma' AND
    Programa NOT LIKE 'Bem Estar - ILARIS' 

    GROUP BY ID_GERAL
    HAVING COUNT(ID_GERAL) > 1)
```

Comment: deu certo, vlw, poremuma duvida.. se eu quiser deixar um unico registro dos duplicados
exemplo: tem 4 duplicados quero que delete 3 e deixe 1

Comment: @MAGUIM apesar de não ter haver com a sua pergunta, de uma olhada no link a seguir, referente a melhorar a "performance de uma consulta com like ‘%String%’ alterando a Collation", já que em sua consulta você está utilizando: 
 [hyperlinks](https://www.fabriciolima.net/blog/2017/02/06/video-melhorando-a-performance-de-uma-consulta-com-like-string-alterando-a-collation/)